# How to call 2 jQuery functions on change in dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, function, onchange, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a simple dropdownlist with a scrollto jQuery onchange (it brings you to a specific place on the website). If one specific selection from the list is clicked, I want to call a change function in jQuery that will show a hidden div element (and will hide it again when an other selection is made after). I manage to get them working separately but not together. Is it possible to have both functions working in the same dropdownlist? I'm quite new to this.

My code parts are as follows:

```
<select id="dropdownlist">
<option value="one">Scroll to place 1</option>
<option value="two">Scroll to place 2</option>
<option value="three">Show hidden div</option>
</select>
```

scollto jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#dropdownlist").on('change',function(){
var project = "#" + $(this).val();
$.scrollTo($(project), 1100);
});
});
</script>
```

show / hide jQuery (seen in this example: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=faq&file=jquery-show-hide-div-using-selectbox):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").change(function(){
$( "select option:selected").each(function(){
if($(this).attr("value")=="three"){
$(".box").hide();
$(".three").show();
}
});
}).change();
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.box { display: none; }
.three{ background: #FFF; }
```

Thank you in advance for thinking along!

Comment: Break the actions into two functions and in your `onchange` call one or the other based on the selection `.val()`.

Comment: Thank you Goose for the reply. Sounds logical but that's what I'm struggling with as I'm new to jQuery (never used it before). Can you maybe write it out for me?

Answer (score 1):

I initiallly said: break the actions out into two functions and call the functions from your onchange based on the selection of the dropdown - but you really don't even need to do that if you won't be reusing them, just include an if statement in your onchange to complete the desired action:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dropdownlist").on('change',function(){
        if ($(this).val() == "three") {
            $(".box").hide();
            $(".three").show();
        } else {
            var project = "#" + $(this).val();
            $.scrollTo($(project), 1100);
        }
    });
});
```